# "Your global Angular CLI version (13.3.7) is greater than your local version (13.3.6). The local Angular CLI version is used."

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, angular8

can someone help me, please! I got this message and tried to fix it by typing the command ng update, but there was no result!

Answer (score 0):

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

Answer (score 0):

1-npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

2-  npm audit fix --force